# Scale Raphael / SVG container to fit all contents

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a number of Raphael / SVG items that could possibly go outside the boundary.  What I want is to be able to auto zoom and center the SVG to show all contents.

I have some partially working code that centers it appropriately, I just cannot figure out how to get the scaling working

**Edit**
This now works... but doesnt center align, and requires padding...

```
var maxValues =  { x: 0, y: 0 };
var minValues =  { x: 0, y: 0 };

//Find max and min points
paper.forEach(function (el) {
    var bbox = el.getBBox();

    if (bbox.y < minValues.y) minValues.y = bbox.y;
    if (bbox.y2 < minValues.y) minValues.y = bbox.y2;

    if (bbox.y > maxValues.y) maxValues.y = bbox.y;
    if (bbox.y2 > maxValues.y) maxValues.y = bbox.y2;

    if (bbox.x < minValues.x) minValues.x = bbox.x;
    if (bbox.x2 < minValues.x) minValues.x = bbox.x2;

    if (bbox.x > maxValues.x) maxValues.x = bbox.x;
    if (bbox.x2 > maxValues.x) maxValues.x = bbox.x2;
});

var w = maxValues.x - minValues.x;
var h = maxValues.y - minValues.y;

console.log(minValues,maxValues,w,h)

paper.setViewBox(minValues.x, minValues.y, w, h, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this snippet of code to center the viewbox that contains all of the SVG that I want to show in almost Full Screen.

```
var elmnt = $(viewport);
var wdif = screen.width - width;
var hdif = screen.height - height;
if (wdif < hdif){
    var scale = (screen.width - 50) / width;
var ty = (screen.height - (height * scale)) / 2
var tx = 20;
}else{
var scale = (screen.height - 50) / height;
var tx = (screen.width - (width * scale)) / 2
var ty = 20;
}
elmnt.setAttribute("transform", "scale("+scale+") translate("+tx+","+ty+")");
```

What it does is to use the difference between the viewport size and the screen size, and use it as the scale. Off course yo need to have all the elements wrapped in a viewbox. I hope this works for you to. Bye!

EDIT

I´ve made this fiddle.... http://jsfiddle.net/MakKZ/

While in the original snippet I´ve used the screen size, on the fiddle, you are going to see I´m using the size of the HTML element that jsfiddle uses. No matter how many circles (or the size of the circles) you draw on the screen you always see them all.

Comment: Hey.. I dont understand how I can use this code? Could you please elaborate or set up a jsFiddle? Cheers